# Can clang/gcc optimize linked-list trees?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, clang

I have a C program that has a tree implemented with linked-lists (child->parent and sibling->sibling).

I'm very green to compiler optimizations. I have seen and read about O-O3 and I think I've read about speeding up nested for loops and such.

If I want to increase performance with my tree implementation, do I need to start thinking about reimplementing it? Or perhaps I can just crunch the compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler optimizations won't change your data structure into something else.  The best you'll get is a local array variable being kept entirely in registers and optimized away.

In theory with whole-program optimization, a compiler *could* figure out what you're doing with a data structure, and use a better one.  In practice, if we had that we'd just tack on some natural-language processing and we'd have an AI to write classes / libraries based on English descriptions.

Your best bet is to use `-O3`.  Or `-Ofast` if `-ffast-math` and similar "unsafe" optimizations are ok.  Even better: use `-profile-generate` and `-fprofile-use` to optimize based on which loops run a lot, and which way branches usually go, and things like that.  This will get the compiler to do as much as possible to minimize any constant factors in the run-time of your algorithm.

---

To improve the worst-case lookup times, you do need to change your algorithm.  Either one of the many flavours of tree that involves re-balancing to avoid degenerate cases, or a different data structure entirely (e.g. hash table).